# Cleaner Match Arms for Deeply Nested Enums

Tags: rust

I have the following function with a match expression:

```
fn handle_event<'e>(&mut self, event: Event<'e>) -> Event<'e> {
    match (&event, &self.current_lang) {
        (Event::Start(Tag::CodeBlock(CodeBlockKind::Fenced(lang))), _) => {
            self.start_fenced_code_block(&lang)
        }
        (Event::End(Tag::CodeBlock(CodeBlockKind::Fenced(_))), _) => {
            self.end_fenced_code_block()
        }
        (Event::Text(text), Some(lang)) => self.code_html(&text, &lang),
        _ => event,
    }
}
```

However, the first two arms felt like they were getting out of hand due to deeply nested enums. So I made some macros:

```
macro_rules! fenced_code_block_start {
    ($lang:pat_param) => {
        Event::Start(Tag::CodeBlock(CodeBlockKind::Fenced($lang)))
    };
}
macro_rules! fenced_code_block_end {
    () => {
        Event::End(Tag::CodeBlock(CodeBlockKind::Fenced(_)))
    };
}
```

and now I have the, IMHO, cleaner:

```
match (&event, &self.current_lang) {
    (fenced_code_block_start!(lang), _) => self.start_fenced_code_block(&lang),
    (fenced_code_block_end!(), _) => self.end_fenced_code_block(),
    (Event::Text(text), Some(lang)) => self.code_html(&text, &lang),
    _ => event,
}
```

However, I'm wondering if there's a better way to do this. Dropping down into macros always give me pause. Is there some other feature of Rust I can use here that isn't such a heavy hammer?

Comment: Of course this is subjective, but I don't see these patterns as too long.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If clarity isn't lost, you can import and use the enum variants directly:

```
fn handle_event<'e>(&mut self, event: Event<'e>) -> Event<'e> {
    use Event::*;
    use Tag::*;
    use CodeBlockKind::*;
    
    match (&event, &self.current_lang) {
        (Start(CodeBlock(Fenced(lang))), _) => self.start_fenced_code_block(&lang),
        (End(CodeBlock(Fenced(_))), _) => self.end_fenced_code_block(),
        (Text(text), Some(lang)) => self.code_html(&text, &lang),
        _ => event,
    }
}
```

Comment: I think that local usages of `use whatever::*;` are underrated.

Comment: @rodrigo they are underrated cross-language IMO.  Too few are willing to utilize `using` in C++ as well inside functions, or scopes.  But too many are willing to do `using namespace std;` in a .h file.  :(

Comment: @kmdreko I think this is exactly what I need. I feel silly for not at least thinking about doing top-level "use"s. But the function scoped use is also a nice touch.